# Why do i have "No connected devices" in Logcat window despite having a virtual device set up already?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm new to Mobile Dev and Android Studio .
I'm trying to disable a button when it gets clicked ...
and i'm trying to log some message to Logcat window using `Log.d("success", "button is disabled now");`
but the Logcat show "No connected devices"
[image]

Any solutions ???

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem. Solved with menu File->Restart IDE.

Comment: yes . that was my fix too !

Comment: The option was File->Repair IDE for me (Android Studio Flamingo). Selecting the operation eventually terminated the existing process and reloaded the project, then the Logcat started working.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue after updating Android Studio, installing the latest SDK Platform-Tools fixed it.

Comment: This only worked. I am using Android Studio zipped extract. I updated it to latest version, did cache invalidate but only updating to latest SDK Platform-Tools fixed it. Thanks